# Call reactive function() outside the shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have created the following reprex which tries to use a reaction function price() outside the shiny app. If i use **df<-5** then the code works but when i use **df<- price()** the code does not work. I have a huge shiny app where i want to source() a huge script outside the shiny app but it takes some input values from a reactive function.

```
 library(shiny)
    df<-price()
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("price", "Price", value=1, min=1 , max=10)
    ,textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    price <- reactive({as.numeric(input$price)})
    output$text<- renderText(df)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I dont want to call the script inside the app because i will have to call it again and again in every sort of output and the script is a simulation which means it changes values each time it is called. I only want to call it once so the values remain the same and i can output them.

---

Trying to use the suggestion by gdevaux. When i try to input the values which come out of a function in a variable it doesnt seem to work. It says 'Error in myfunction(argument1) : object 'argument1' not found
'.

```
library(shiny)

# in script.R
myfunction <- function(argument1){
    return(as.numeric(argument1))
}
f<-myfunction(argument1)  #Trying to put output values in a variable

# in app.R
#source("script.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("price", "Price", value=1, min=1 , max=10)
    ,textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    price <- reactive(myfunction(argument1 = input$price))
    output$text<- renderText(price())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You cannot define a function in the server (or ui) and then use it outside, nor call inputs values outside. What you can do is write your functions outside of the server, source it, and pass your inputs or reactive as arguments to these functions

Comment: Can you give a little example? I am still a little new to R and i am trying to wrap my head around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a function in the server (or ui) and then use it outside, nor call inputs values outside of a shiny app. What you can do is write your functions outside of the server (in another file for example), source it, and pass your inputs or reactive as arguments to these functions

```
library(shiny)

# in script.R
myfunction <- function(argument1){
  return(as.numeric(argument1))
}

# in app.R
#source("script.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("price", "Price", value=1, min=1 , max=10)
  ,textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  price <- reactive(myfunction(argument1 = input$price))
  output$text<- renderText(price())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a project at my job which i have to submit by wednesday. This might just be the thing which might save me. I will try it out! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I tried adding the values which came out from the function in a variable ( i have edited my question with the code). Any idea what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: `argument1` is an argument for the function, not an existing variable. Which means you need to give it a value when calling the function. `f<-myfunction(argument1="5")`

Comment: I wanted it to get values from the reactive function automatically so i could further use it in my script